# Git: how to undo modifications being pushed after a merge

Tags: git, heroku, merge

I merged a remote local branch with plenty of modifications with my master branch. Then I wanted to just push one commit with modifications in only one file to my heroku master branch (production), I did the following:

> git add path_of_my_file
>
> git commit -m "fix bug"
>
> git push heroku master

But it also pushed all the modifications I did before merging my remote branch. I then did `heroku rollback`

Now each time I try to push a commit, all the modifications from the remote branch are also pushed.

How can I just push the commit containing the modifications within my file?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `git cherry-pick <commit>` from one branch to another instead of `git merge`. `git-merge` is used when you need all the commits of a branch. It brings commits and their changes by default.

Comment: Yes, now I know, I will not make the mistake twice!